# Vue.js @change and $event.target.value issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this very basic HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" @change="start=$event.target.value">
  <input type="number" @change="final=$event.target.value">
  <button v-bind:disabled="isButtonActive">Proceed</button>
  {{start}} -- {{final}} -- {{res}}
</div>
```

And small vue.js code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      start: 0,
      final: 0
  },
  computed: {
      res() {
        return this.start < this.final;
      }
  },
  methods: {
    isButtonActive() {
      return this.start < this.final;
    }
  }
})
```

Now for the issue:
If I put 2 to first input and 12 to second I got
`'2 -- 12' -- false`, but why - 2 < 12?

If I put 12 to second input first and then 2 to the first I got

```
'2 -- 12 -- true'
```

If I change 2 to 45 I got
`'45 -- 12 -- true'`, oh

And now matter 'true' or 'false' button never becomes active. Please help.
Here is the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/Paradoxetion/pen/pVqNKK)

Comment: You are making your code harder than it should be. Use `v-model="start"` instead of `@change="start=$event.target.value"`

Comment: If you want to use the method, you have to actually call the method, `v-bind:disabled="isButtonActive()"`. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GdPrVY?editors=1010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because the value of `$event.target.value` is one string, not number, you can convert string to number by [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
check below demo.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      start: 0,
      final: 0
  },
  computed: {
      res() {
        console.log(typeof this.start, typeof this.final, this.start < this.final)
        console.log('[Use ParseInt]', parseInt(this.start) < parseInt(this.final))
        return this.start < this.final;
      }
  },
  methods: {
    isButtonActive() {
      return this.start < this.final;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" @change="start=$event.target.value">
  <input type="number" @change="final=$event.target.value">
  <button v-bind:disabled="isButtonActive">Proceed</button>
  {{start}} -- {{final}} -- {{res}}
</div>
```

You can use **the modifier**= [v-model.number](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number) then you should `v-bind:disabled` with the result(`isButtonActive()`) of the function instead of the function itself(`isButtonActive`), or use `v-bind:disabled="res"` **will be better**. ([the difference between computed properties and methods is that computed properties are cached based on their dependencies](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)), you can hit **click me** button to see the differences.

like below demo:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      start: 0,
      final: 0,
      testText: 'You will see isButtonActive is invoked, but computed properties will not'
  },
  computed: {
      res() {
        console.log('computed=res', typeof this.start, typeof this.final)
        return this.start < this.final;
      }
  },
  methods: {
    isButtonActive() {
      console.log('isButtonActive', typeof this.start, typeof this.final)
      return this.start < this.final;
    },
    test: function () {
      this.testText += '!'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model.number="start">
  <input type="number" v-model.number="final">
  <button v-bind:disabled="isButtonActive()">Proceed</button>
  <button v-bind:disabled="res">Proceed</button>
  {{start}} -- {{final}} -- {{res}}
  <hr>
  <button @click="test()">Click me!!!</button>
  <p>{{testText}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, TIL about the `.number` modifier

Comment: @Sphinx, Thanks a lot, but what if I don't want to use v-model? I can go for parseInt(), but maybe it's easier way?

Comment: @Paradoxetion uses [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) before compare.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to convert string to number. You can simply get the value as a number without transforming it :

`$event.target.valueAsNumber`

More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68177209/12247829