# type of event.target.value should be changed to integer in react

Tags: javascript

I have an input field and When we enter the value in the input field I am updating the state with the entered value using event.target.value. By default the `event.target.value` be a string. Can we convert that into an integer ?

```
    const func=(props)=>{
      return(
      <div>
     <input type="text" onChange={props.change} value={props.value}/>
     </div>
    )};

   // handler function
   changeHandler =(event)=>{
      this.setState({data:event.target.value})
   };
```

My state has integer value that i assigned to Zero (data:0). So while updating the state using changeHandler function data becomes string.I want to typecast the event.target.value to the integer.

Comment: use `parseInt` function

Comment: Why you are not accepting any answer? Is there anything wrong or missing in my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68177209/12247829)?

Answer (score 41):

Actually there is a more direct way. You can simply get the value as a number without transforming it :

`event.target.valueAsNumber`

Also for edge cases use it like `const value = isNaN(e.target.valueAsNumber) ? null : e.target.valueAsNumber;`

Answer (score 12):

Here is a syntactic sugar version of the other answers which will also attempt to convert your value to an int (or return NaN) in base `10` :

```
this.setState({data: +event.target.value });
```

Answer (score 7):

***Solution 1:*** (I highly recommend)

```
console.log($event.target.valueAsNumber) // Use valueAsNumber instead of value
```

**Note:** `$event.target.valueAsNumber` *is not avilable for few input elements such as select, options etc.* In that case use Solution 2.
(@Mads Hjorth)

***Solution 2:***

use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` or `Number()`

```
var integer = Number('613613');
// var integer = parseFloat('613613');
// var integer = parseInt('613613', radix); // radix is option parameter
```

**Why this error?**

`$event.target.value` will always be a string or undefined.
`$event.target.value` is only available for input type element. For example, if I click a div then `$event.target` is a div that does not have `value` property.

Comment: This confused me a bit. To clarify, $event.target.valueAsNumber is not viable for input elements such as select options etc. but $event.target.value is, right? Thus you have to use e.g. parseInt when getting values from input elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by parsing the string to an integer:

```
this.setState({data: parseInt(event.target.value, 10) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `parseInt` function.[Documentation on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
this.setState({data: parseInt(event.target.value, X)})
```

Where `X` is your radix (per documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using parseFloat(). In your case, you can try

```
changeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ data: parseFloat(event.target.value) });
};
```

But make sure to only use this handler when numbers will be added or else you get an error `NaN` in `state.data`

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeHandler(event: any) {
        let { name, valueAsNumber, value } = event.target;
        setStateVariable((prevState: stateVariableInterface| undefined) => ({
          ...prevState,
          [name]: Number.isNaN(valueAsNumber) ? value : valueAsNumber,
        }));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

event.target.valueAsNumber works.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers.